# How do I change the first bar color in a canvasjs stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I'm working on a project for which I want a sideways stacked bar chart.  This needs to be written in JavaScript, and the best library I've found for what I need is CanvasJS.  In the chart I'm creating, the colors used in the stacked bar are not just for distinguishing the different bars, the colors also have meaning.  Because of this, I would like it if I could specify the color for each part of the stacked bar independently from the other bars.

[Here is the page for the specific kind of chart I want](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-stacked-bar-chart/)

On this page, the example they provide has 5 bars, each with colors blue, red, purple, green, light blue.  For all 5 bars, the colors go in the same order.  I would like to be able to mix up the order independently, so that I could have a bar that goes red > green > yellow, another one that goes green > yellow > red, etc.

If you know how to do this, or if you know of another graphing library that I could do this in, I would really appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is simply a matter of adding a color attribute to each datapoint individually:

```
{ x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 71, color: "red" }
```

...which can be done for each datapoint any way you like.